# SQL Server 2005 inserting image

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 connected with C# winforms app. I added new field of type image, then I inserted the data manually from `show table data` option, can someone tell me how to insert the image manually? And which type is the best for image? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by inserting it manually? Typing in the bytes one at a time?

Comment: i am typing the other string fields so is there a way to attach an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in DB image save in binary format.

Answer (score 1):

The data type `IMAGE` is deprecated as of SQL Server 2005 - you should use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead, which also support up to 2 GB in size.